# How to calculate 95% confidence interval for AUC from confusion matrix?

Tags: confidence-interval, confusion-matrix, auc

From a classification model in Weka software I get: sample size, confusion matrix and AUC (area under curve of ROC).
How may I calculate the 95% confidence interval for AUC?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have everything you need so follow the following equation:

**Note**: N1 and N2 are the sample sizes of each group

[image]

Comment: I hope this works also for a cross validation result. Are N1 the TP + FN in confusion matrix (for example  number of all cases with a pathology)? And are N2  the FP + TN (number of all cases without a pathology)? The formula is applicable for large sample; I have small sample (20 Pz with pathology and 20 without pathology); may I use the same the formula?

Comment: Hello. N1 and N2 are the sample sizes of each group. The formula is okay for your sample size I believe. Also, you have balanced groups.

Comment: To people who come across this answer - this is Hanley and McNeil (1982) calculation. You might want to try DeLong's method or bootstrapping from the pROC package instead.